# Solving partial differential equation using separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem

I recently learnt about solving partial differential equations using method of separation of variables.

The problem: Find a solution of the equation $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + 2u$ in the form $u = f(x)g(y)$. Solve the equation subject to the conditions $u = 0$ and $\frac{du}{dx} = 1 + e^{-3y}$ when $x = 0$ for all values of $y$.

Solution: On taking $u = f(x)g(y)$, I get $f(x) = c_1e^{2x} + c_2e^{-x}$. I assume $u = g(y)(c_1e^{2x} + c_2e^{-x})$ and then apply the boundary conditions. I end up getting couple of conditions: $c_1+c_2 = 0$ and $g(y) = \frac{1 + e^{-3y}}{2c_1-c_2}$ and then I am stuck.

How to calculate the constants and $g(y)$ here? No equation for $g(y)$ seems to be there. The given answer is: $u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}sinh\sqrt{2}x + e^{-3y}sinx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done. Put $c_2=-c_1$ in $g$ and $u$ to get $g(y)=\frac{1+e^{-3y}}{3c_1}$ and $u(x,y)=g(y)c_1(e^{2x}-e^{-x})$, and therefore
$$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{3}(1+e^{-3y})(e^{2x}-e^{-x})$$

Remark: Although this is a valid method to get a solution, it is pretty uncommon to use for these kind of problems, since there is no derivative wrt the variable $y$ in the equation. Treating this problem as ODE instead (by taking $c_1,c_2$ to be functions of $y$), will get you the same result, but will prove this is the only solution to the problem.

Comment: What you have shared does make sense but how will this reduce to the final answer that is given for this problem?

Comment: The solution you added at the end is not correct. Although it satisfies both conditions, it fails to solve the equation (you can easily check it yourself). Moreover, it is not of the form $f(x)g(y)$.

Comment: oh , yea, you are right. I should've checked. Thanks.